# onClick() causing a Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

In the render method, why does it not like this.increment in the onClick attribute? I'm not sure how the maximum update depth error relates. Sorry, I'm new to react and couldn't find much documentation on this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState(
            {
                count: this.state.count + 1
            },
            () => {
                console.log('Callback value', this.state.count)
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div> Count - {this.state.count}</div>
                <button onClick={this.increment()}> Increment </button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Counter
```

Comment: Change this `onClick={this.increment()}` to `onClick={this.increment}` that should solve it

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `onClick` refer to `this.increment` not calling it.

To fix the issue do this `onClick={this.increment}` or `onClick={() => this.increment}`. I also suggest you to do a quick reading on `Event Handling` in the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Answer (score 1):

`onClick={this.increment()}` to `onClick={this.increment}`. You have to refer a pointer to the function on onclick.